# jUnit HTML Reporting - Printing assert/verify Failures alongside the test case in HTML log

Tags: ant, selenium, junit, slf4j

A little background of what we are doing:

1. We are using Ant and jUnit framework for carrying out UI testing of our websites using an open source Selenmium RC tool.
2. At the end of test execution, HTML reports are produced using the Ant task jUnitreport. The test pass, fail stats are represented there with intuitive HTML navigation from test suite to test case level status.
3. The logging and assert failure messages go into the console, which is available by following a link in HTML test report at the bottom of the report.

Question:
The above report of logs is a run down log of all test cases together. Is there a way we control the logging to be tied up to the test case level in the HTML table report of jUnit.. like the logs related to each test cases should just show within the HTML test summary table.

For example, when an unhandled exception is raised, jUnit displays this error in the Summary table against the test. Can we display the logs in that format as well?

I use slf4j logging.

Any help on this greatly appreciated..

Regards,
Prakash